# I am trying to display an image from MYSQL via PHP in an HTML file. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Here is the PHP code. What I'm basically trying to do is display a single image from a mySQL database, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out.

```
    <?php
    $port = "****";
    $server = "****".$port;
    $dbname ="****";
     $user = "****";

    $conn = mysql_connect ("$server", "$user", "$pass") or die ("Connection
    Error or Bad Port");

    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Missing Database");

    ?>

     <!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
    />
     <title>Query 3</title>
     </head>

   <body bgcolor="white">


    <hr>


      <?php
    $speakerPic = $_POST['speakerPic'];
    $query = "SELECT speaker.speaker_picture FROM  Speaker JOIN Contact USING(contact_id) 
    WHERE Contact.lname = ";
    $query = $query."'".$speakerPic."';";
    ?>

        <p>
    The query:
    <p>
    <?php
    print $query;
    ?>

    <hr>
    <p>
     Result of query:
    </p>

     <?php
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   $content = $row['image'];

   header('Content-type: image/jpg');
         echo $content;
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

What isn't working here? I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: Obligatory: `$speakerPic` is open to SQL injection.

Comment: Your Doctype is nonsense. You have a transitional public identifier and a strict system identifier. They don't match. Pick [a real doctype](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

Comment: Further to @nickb's comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

To include an image in an HTML document you use an `<img>` tag with a `src` attribute that contains a URI pointing at the image.

That could be an HTTP URI (which could hit a PHP script that gets the image data from a database and returns it) and it could be a [DATA URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) with the image encoded directly into the page.

The usual approach to dealing with images is to keep them on a filesystem and store URLs (or file paths that URLs can be constructed from) in the database.

You *can't* just spit out an HTTP response in the middle of another HTTP response as you are trying to do now.

Comment: This is correct. Also, mysql_fetch_array() on an SQL string won't do much, the query should be (prepared and) executed ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query) before you call [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array).

```
$result = mysql_query( $query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Also, you should sanitize `$speakerPic` like so:

```
$query = $query."'". mysql_real_escape_string( $speakerPic)."';";
```

Comment: I added the $result variable, and now when I run it I get this following error code, when I run the query from the html page itself.  The image "http://......./query2.php" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Answer (score 0):

you have no row called "image", try re-naming your row in your query like this:

```
SELECT speaker.speaker_picture AS image FROM ...
```